# OpenCV 2.4 CascadeClassified detectMultiScale arguments

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-wavelet

I was looking at the objectdetect sample and tried it with a couple of body detection cascades(*haarcascade_fullbody/haarcascade_upperbody/haarcascade_lowerbody,haarcascade_mcs_upperbody*) on some footage I took with a camera of a pedestrian bridge. So far so good, but it's a demanding functionality.

I though thinks might run smoother if I pass the min/max Sizes since my camera is always in the same place and I figure out the min/max bounding boxes. Unfortunately I ran into syntax errors when trying to do so:

```
//my call
body.detectMultiScale( gray, bodies, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30),cv::Size(0,0),cv::Size(5,13),cv::Size(45,80));
//errors:
main.cpp:43: error: no matching function for call to 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size, cv::Size, cv::Size, cv::Size)'
/opt/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp:383: note: candidates are: virtual void cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size, cv::Size)
/opt/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp:393: note:                 virtual void cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, double, int, int, cv::Size, cv::Size, bool)
```

I simply added two `cv::Size` objects as the min max, but to be honest I'm not sure:

1. Why the previous arguments are Size() objects as well when the docs
   list them as ints ?
2. Am I looking at the wrong docs or at the docs
   in a wrong way ?

> C++: void CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const Mat& image,
>   vector& objects, double scaleFactor=1.1, int minNeighbors=3, int
>   flags=0, Size minSize=Size(), Size maxSize=Size())

from docs.

Comment: Why are you passing `cv::Size` for `minNeighbors` and `flags`?

Comment: That's one of the questions I had. I simply copied the call from the [objectdetect.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/objectDetection/objectDetection.cpp?rev=6483) sample

Comment: The main reason is to get to the `minSize`, `maxSize` arguments which I haven't found a setter method for, so the constructor seems the only access point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I was passing the wrong arguments. This worked:

```
body.detectMultiScale(gray,bodies,1.1,3,3,cv::Size(5,13),cv::Size(45,80));
```

Comment: have you tried [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=detectmultiscale#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) ? `Python: cv.HaarDetectObjects(image, cascade, storage, scale_factor=1.1, min_neighbors=3, flags=0, min_size=(0, 0)) → detectedObjects`

Comment: Yes yes, I made the program, forgot that I had commented. It's all good now. :)

Comment: Hi George, from where I can get the cascades for the human detection? Do you think this will work in real time with multiple cameras?

Comment: In your opencv install path or opencv source folder you will find these haar cascade files: `haarcascade_fullbody.xml`,`haarcascade_lowerbody.xml`,`haarcascade_upperbody.xml`. Regarding real time and multiple cameras it totally depends on the setup(the scene: how complex is it, the lighting: how good is it, the camera: how much control do you have over the settings, etc.). Haar cascades are slower than LBP cascades for example, so I recommend you scale the webcam frames down, do the detection, then scale the resulting detection rectangles back up. You will need to tweak values to find the best

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue in my case. Following line worked for me. If you consider, I am only providing the minimum size `cv::Size(45,80)`.
I am still investigating about other parameters but this is working currently.

```
haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,faces,1.1,3,3,cv::Size(45,80));
```